# JS Нахождение одинаковых пар ключ-значение в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как эффективнее всего находить элементы массива с одинаковыми значениями ключей? Приведу простой пример.

```js
let book = [{
    id: 1,
    urlAddress: 'Monday-starts-on-Saturday',
    bookName: "Понедельник начинается в субботу",
    seriesNumber: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    urlAddress: "Harry-Potter-and-the-Order-of-the-Phoenix",
    bookName: "Гарри Поттер и Орден Феникса",
    seriesNumber: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    urlAddress: "The-Tale-of-the-Three-Pigs",
    bookName: "Сказание о трех свинах",
    seriesNumber: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    urlAddress: "Harry-Potter-and-the-Philosopher's-Stone",
    bookName: "Гарри Поттер и философский камень",
    seriesNumber: 2,
  },
];

let list = document.getElementById("myList");
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Как найти все книги со значением seriesNumber: 2 и записать значения их имен в ul ?
Что б было

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Гарри Поттер и Орден Феникса</li><li>Гарри Поттер и Орден Феникса</li></ul>
```

Comment: Цикл for() тут ведь не очень эффективен... если допустим таких записей > 100

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что цикл `for` тут не очень эффективен?

Comment: Эмм, а с чего вдруг цикл for не очень эффективен? Как раз таки наоборот, цикл `for` самый эффективный из всех возможных решений

Comment: Цикл for действительно не эффективен при большом числе записей. Но вообще, подобные "тяжелые" запросы обычно выполняют на сервере. Однако сделать быстро можно и на фронте, и на беке: с помощью hash-таблицы. Hash подходит, если есть много однотипных запросов поиска

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, какая связь между for и hash-таблицей, чтобы их сравнивать по эффективности?

Comment: @Grundy простая. for в данном случае имеет линейную сложность, в то время как hash -- константную (при условии, что временем подготовки данных можно принебречь)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, если у тебя есть только массив - ты не сможешь построить hashset без `for`, а в задаче есть указание только на массив

Comment: @Mikhail Ionkin, на фронте for не эффективен, поэтому мы загрузим бек?

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы извлечь необходимые объекты можно воспользоваться либо `for()` как писали раньше, либо `reduce()`

Вот пример с использованием `reduce()`

```
    function reducer(acc, value) {
        if (value.seriesNumber === 2) {
        acc.push(value);
      }
        return acc;
    }
    
    const filterBooks = book.reduce(reducer, []);
```

В html элемент можно позже положить с помощью `el.innerHTML`

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю что эффективнее, но вот просто рабочий код:

```js
const books = [{
    id: 1,
    urlAddress: 'Monday-starts-on-Saturday',
    bookName: "Понедельник начинается в субботу",
    seriesNumber: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    urlAddress: "Harry-Potter-and-the-Order-of-the-Phoenix",
    bookName: "Гарри Поттер и Орден Феникса",
    seriesNumber: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    urlAddress: "The-Tale-of-the-Three-Pigs",
    bookName: "Сказание о трех свинах",
    seriesNumber: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    urlAddress: "Harry-Potter-and-the-Philosopher's-Stone",
    bookName: "Гарри Поттер и философский камень",
    seriesNumber: 2,
  },
];

const filteredBooks = books.slice().filter(item => item.seriesNumber === 2);

const ul = document.querySelector('#ul');

filteredBooks.forEach(item => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = item.bookName;
  ul.append(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
</ul>
```

Comment: Михаил, а зачем .slice() добавлялся, я что-то не могу понять ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 чтобы сделать полную копию массива, чтобы не изменять исходный массив, т.к. filter изменяет массив по ссылке